# Creating Inheritance chart /uml diagram of existing android eclipse projects

Tags: android, uml

I want to Create inheritance charts (Class diagram in UML view) of a big existing android application.
The app that i am studying contains a lot of inheritance, abstract classes, interfaces. So it has become really difficult to track the whole project.

So if any plugin exists for eclipse that could help me do that, Please share it with me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Found a link for my question's answer..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120032/what-is-your-favorite-automatic-class-diagram-generator-for-eclipse